# Mono for Android - How It works?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I found that Xamarin apps run in Mono runtinme on Android, and things get passed to Dalvik. But what I can not understant is how is it possible that app is running in Mono, but normal app are executed in Dalvik. What is so different in Mono app that it runs in Mono and not Dalvik.

How can Mono be on the same level as Dalvik? Mono should be somehow stored in the app which runs in Dalvik, I think.

Please explain to me how is it possible, and sorry for my bad language.

[image: Architecture]

Comment: I do not know why so many downvotes and close question requests? If the answer is so obvious, please make it quick

Comment: Due to the open source nature of both Mono and Dalvik/Android, while Xamarin.Android is not open source, your question about the technical details, can only lead to suspicion of your intentions. Are you really curious about the technical details, or you plan to clone it from scratch? SO is a place for knowledge exchange, but I don't think it is a place for reverse engineering. BTW, I did not down vote your question yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An app developed by xamarin has the mono runtime which it takes with it onto the device. The app apk contains .net intermediate code, p-code, which obviously is not Dalvik understandable.

Xamarin.Android developers access the various features in the operating system either by calling into .NET APIs that they know (for low-level access) or using the classes exposed in the Android namespaces which provides a bridge to the Java APIs that are exposed by Dalvik.

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/ this is where you can find more details.

Comment: OK, I get that. But when I run a normal java app it runs in Dalvik. Something in app specifies in which runtime it will run ? What I do not understand is how Dalvik can be on the same level as Mono, when Mono is contained in the app

Comment: When you have android apps written in java, they are compiled to bytecode. They are then converted from JVM-compatible Java class files to Dalvik-compatible .dex and odex files before installation on a device.

But here you have apps written in c#. So there is a need of something which can handle the c# assemblies, which obviously is mono. 

MFA(Mono For Android) providing a Mono runtime, may wrap things around and calls down to the Dalvik runtime or it may even bypass Dalvik completely. What will happen depends upon the code.

Comment: Now, Mono is not present on android devices by default. So, there has to be a way in which it can be made to be put and run on the device.
Thus, an application package is an obvious way in which we can get this done. And even we can have mono running which in turn can run our app. Do accept the answer if it helped you in some way.