# How to check Mono Version in Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I want to know which Mono version my project uses. How can I check it?

In my project I have Mono.Android DLL. I have right clicked on it and review property. It says Runtime Version: 4.0.3. If I go to location of that DLL, I am getting this location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\Mono.Android.dll

I am confused with what is version of Mono. And what is Mono.Android. Please help me

Following information I got from Help --> About Visual Studio

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.5.4
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.5.4+27130.2024
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03056

Installed Version: Enterprise

Visual Basic 2017
Microsoft Visual Basic 2017

Visual C# 2017
Microsoft Visual C# 2017

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.8.4-pre (3fe64e3)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   4.5.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.27130.2020
The Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a single universal app experience that can reach every device running Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft Windows 10 Software Development Kit.

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Xamarin   4.8.0.757 (7f9ec2a)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   4.8.188 (c5813fa34)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin.Android SDK   8.1.3.0 (HEAD/ef47226b7)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.6.1.2 (6857dfc)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have Mono android integrated with visual studio so you can't find it from 
*Help --> About Visual Studio*. 
There is no more `monoDoid` now it becomes `Xamarin.Android`.
`Xamarin.Android` applications run within the Mono execution environment which it takes with it onto the device. Thus, an **application package** is an obvious way in which we can get this done. So mono itself is xamarin.android. Here you are using mono android version v6.0 which you have targeted for your application & Runtime Version: 4.0.3 is your version of *.NET runtime assembly*.

**Mono-** The Mono framework is an open source implementation of Microsoft’s .NET Framework based on the open standards for the C# language and the Common Language Runtime.
The Mono project has been in active development for over a decade and is used - behind the scenes - in many products. Developer used to use it with *Visual Studio 2010*.
For more information visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/internals/architecture) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576685/mono-for-android-how-it-works)

Hope it help you.